# Are there any true aerobatic helicopters that aren’t built around the Bo-105?

Tags: helicopter, aerobatics

I know that some aerobatic maneuvers have been performed (legally or otherwise) in many different models of helicopters. However, to my knowledge, I have only heard of Bo-105s being specifically modified for this purpose, supposedly due to their hingeless rotor system. Are there any other aerobatic models flying at air shows in other parts of the world?

Comment: The AH64 will loop, roll, and hammerhead.